# Which is the best way to fetch real time data based on logged in user?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My project is built in .net MVC with MS SQL Server. I am fetching live rates in my project, these rates are updated every milliseconds,. My problem is that I need to show all these rates on browser to logged in users depending on their settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at SignalR. You can update to all connected clients by using signalr hub.

Comment: have a look at [this GIT](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-StockTicker) example also it will helpful

Comment: I've been looking at angular js library - I believe it can do real time, partial refreshes on web pages